# Charts like VisualVM Threads view

Tags: java, jvm, jfreechart, visualvm, jvisualvm

I would like to create a chart that shows the state of several threads over time. Graphically, it is like the VisualVM Threads view.

Basically, it would be a Gantt diagram that has multiple states for a given task, or a horizontal stacked bar chart with time as the X axis.

Do anyone know an open-source library to do such graphs ? I have tried JFreecharts but I cannot create a `Task` with multiples duration over time.

Any idea ?

[image: VisualVM Threads view]

Comment: If you want to create dynamic charts in a web application using javascript, you can use one of those libraries: http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/css/top-jquery-chart-libraries-interactive-charts/.

Comment: I don't think I can use Javascript. I need read/write access to the file system so this cannot run in a browser.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about which library to use for your requirements, but visualVM is open source and you can see the source code at https://java.net/projects/visualvm/sources/svn/show